# Restful resource with non restful method? (Ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller CourseSteps with 3 columns course_id, step_id, position. It has create, index, and destroy actions that work fine.

I need to perform a function that swaps two position values. I don't think this fits in the "update" method as I am changing 2 rows. Should I make a new method called swap_position? Does it make sense to have a position column for this model? (It basically creates a many to many relationship between courses and steps. (Courses can have many steps and steps can related to many courses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add routes to a single resource like this:

```
resources :your_resources do
    member do
       post swap_position
    end
 end
```

You can add methods to a collection, as below:

```
resources :your_resource do
    collection do
       post swap_position
    end
 end
```

Of course, you are not limited to only 'post'; any RESTful verb can be used.  In your case, you would want to do a post or a get.

Edit: You can read more about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html  Read section 2.9